# Named Subexpressions error in Boost Regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I'm trying to use named subexpressions to replace multiple patterns in the input string using boost::regex_replace and named subexpressions.

I use the following code:

```
std::string s="Sun Fun Gun Tic Tac Toe ;$!";
boost::regex expr("(?<from1>.un)|(?<from2>[:;!])"); //Throws the error
std::string fmt("(?'from1'nm)(?'from2'sp)");
std::string s2 = boost::regex_replace(s,expr,fmt,boost::match_default|boost::format_all);
std::cout<<s2<<std::endl;
```

However, when run thos throws the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::regex_error'
what():  Invalid preceding regular expression
Aborted
```

Please guide as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: version of boost? http://liveworkspace.org/code/5fe67c46a9325236ff224de62c944198

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Boost, but `std::regex` (in TR1 and C++11), which was based on Boost, doesn't support named subexpressions.

Comment: The following page describes support for Perl Regex syntax in Boost Libraries: [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).

So, I believe it does support the same.

Comment: @Mindstorm - thanks for the link. They changed it after the standard adopted it (the standard doesn't do perl; the default is ECMAScript, which is not a synonym for "perl").

Comment: @Mindstorm - this doesn't affect the line that's marked "Throws the error", but it looks like the format string should be something like `"$+{from1}nm$+{from2}sp"`. That is, `$+{NAME}` "[o]utputs whatever matched the sub-expression named 'NAME'".

Comment: Changing to $+{NAME} didn't help either. It throws the same error.


The reason why I said that line throws the error is because the error occurs when I try to define an expression using that string, irrespective of whether I define the following format string and do the replace or not.

Comment: @Mindstorm - yes, that's what I meant to imply in my previous comment. I was just showing off the results of my research, starting with the link you provided.